# Selenium FindElement, element found and assigned, but results in "exception with a null response" exception

Tags: selenium, exception, null, webdriver

```
        public static void tryIt()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://al.acccins.com/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        IWebElement pageElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnDemo"));

        pageElement.Click();
    }
```

FindElement locates the element. Element shows a value of "**id = 55d94413-5d26-402f-b6f1-291036b9xd9f**".

When the script then tries to run `pageElement.Click();` I get a **WebDriverException** that says "**A exception with a null response was thrown sending HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL....**"

Anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: Figured out a work-around. Rather than .Click() I instead tried .SendKeys(Keys.Return) and that works. Ugh.. whatever.